# How can you represent a Huffman-tree in Hex?

Tags: binary, huffman-coding

I was trying to store a Huffman tree in a binary file recently. I thought it wouldn't be a big problem since you actually have the binary codes already in front of you.

Well, the difference is that the file (in the hex editor) is logically coded in hex. So I tried to convert the "characters" from binary to hex. Without any success.

**Let's take this tree as an example:**

[image: Huffman-tree]

My first attempt was to simply convert Binary to Hex. So for example `01` became `0x01`. But there is a problem now: There are duplicates. So `01` as well as just `1` both became `0x01`.

So I couldn't use that. I also tried to just represent the  zeros and ones in hex, for example: `10 1...` (The equivalent of 1 01) but that wouldn't be really efficient anymore.

---

So how could I now make a Huffman tree in Hex? Would I maybe even have to use a different encoding?

I hope I could describe my problem well enough.

Comment: My guess would be binary tree for binary representation, and 16-ary tree for hexadecimal, but that may be a simple approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This practical problem comes up in JPEG, where you can define your own Huffman tables. The codewords are limited to 16 bits, and the table is stored as follows:

- For $\ell=1,\ldots,16$, the number of codewords of length $\ell$ bits.
- For each $\ell$, a list of the values encoded by the codewords of length $\ell$.

The codewords themselves need not be stored, since a Huffman code can be extracted from this description. See [Imran Nazar's notes](http://imrannazar.com/Let%27s-Build-a-JPEG-Decoder%3A-Huffman-Tables).